# How would you define this conditions on a simple undirected and connected graph?

Tags: graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I am stuck on this problem. It is about a simple, undirected and connected graph G on N nodes. It says to consider two vertices *u* and *v* s.t.

- A(*u,v*) = 0 (with A being the adjacency matrix for G)
- $$\sum_{z=1}^{n} A(u,z)A(v,z) = 0$$

As for the first condition I know it means that there is no edge between *u* and *v*. But as for the second, does it mean that there are no edges in general linking both *u* and *v* to the same node *z*?

It then says to consider the graph G’ on N - 1 nodes obtained from G by merging *u* and *v* in a single node. It wants me to show that G’ is also a simple, undirected and connected graph.

Comment: You'll have to clarify your notations. Is A thr adjacency matrix? And what is the definition for $*u$ and $u*$?

Comment: You should use subscripts to denote elements of the matrix $A$ : write $A_{u,v}$ (latex is A_{u,v} ) rather than $A(u,v)$.

Comment: Two vertices at distance at least $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every $A_{i,j}$ is either 0 or 1, the second condition amounts to say that for all $z$, $A_{u,z}A_{v,z} = 0$, ie **there is no vertex $w\in V$ such that both $u$ and $v$ are both connected to $w$**.

Say $G$ has vertices $V$ and edges $E$.
For the graph $G'$, we have $G' = (V',E')$ where :
$$V' = V \setminus\{v\}$$
$$ E' = \{(a,b)\in E \big| \ a\neq v\} \sqcup \{(u,b) \big| \ (v,b) \in E\}$$

Your first condition ($A_{u,v} = 0$) implies that $(u,u) \notin E'$.
Your second condition implies that you don't have a double edge from $u$ to any vertex.
Hence, $G'$ is simple.